# using template file to generate powerpoint slides via R Markdown

Tags: r, r-markdown, powerpoint

I've been trying to play around with RMD files to generate powerpoint slide decks. One of the critical features for me is to be able to use a custom template. Starting off with the basic template in R Studio, the only edit I made was to include a single line in the YAML header to designate the custom template:

```
---
title: "Powerpoint trial"
author: "Mario Niepel"
date: "2/1/2021"
output: 
  powerpoint_presentation:
    reference_doc: template.pptx
---
```

Without this line the PPT comes out exactly as described in the instructions:

[image: Powerpoint deck as it should be.]

However, when I include the template I get a warning:

[image: Warning that Powerpoint slide deck requires repairs.]

And when I ask to attempt to repair the presentation, it is mostly garbled:

[image: Content of Powerpoint deck after repair attempt.]

Even though the slide master in my template is properly designated, in the new version the slide master is essentially empty:

[image: Slide master view of knitted document.]

Is there a place the lists the exact requirements for a template? Is there something else I should be checking?

---

EDIT: In addition, I read up on the description for powerpoint/rmarkdown use of templates that says four levels of slides are needed for the template (Title, Title + Content, Section Header, Two Content). Those are the only four slide layouts I currently have in my template.

Comment: The docs for the `officer` package have some helpful info on using templates, and you could alternatively try using the `officer` package if you can't get the template to work with R markdown: https://ardata-fr.github.io/officeverse/office-documents-generation.html#templates

Comment: What's your ```rmarkdown``` version?

Comment: I'm running ‘rmarkdown’ version 2.6.